# how to store xml string of large siza in GAE data store

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i've XML document object that is converted to String and i'm using this string to store it as entity on GAE data store but it's only some part is stored not fully.that's what i'm doing

```
Text text = new Text(xmlString);
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Entity greeting = new Entity("categories");
greeting.setProperty("xmlEntity", text);


datastore.put(greeting);
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with it why the xml string is not completely being stored on GAE data store why only few characters?

any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the size of your `xmlString`? The limit for `Text` properties  is 1Mb.

Comment: thanks for response! the xmlString has 30,000 characters in it.

Comment: When you retrieve data are you using `text.toString()`?

Comment: yes,i fetch like entity.getProperty("xmlEntity").toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving Text properties' data you should not use [`text.toString()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text#toString%28%29) as this is used for human-readable representation and returns only first 70 chars.

Use [`text.getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text#getValue%28%29) instead.

Comment: there is no getValue() method for entity.getProperty("xmlEntity").getValue(); but if i cast it into Text and get this in text object then output again same,I think there is problem in storing.